# Visualize DNA sequence on JSP Struct Web Page

Tags: java, jquery, html, dna-sequence, sequence-alignment

We have to visualize the DNA sequence Alignment slimier to blast visualizer like below >our project is a web based one having Java back-end with JSP,Struct

Currently needed way to visualize
http://eagle.fish.washington.edu/Arabidopsis/20110721%20PGS2%20BLAST%20Alignment.png

HTML tables cannot use to visualize the dynamic content .Alignment information is already generated and We need to know a method to visualize in slimier manner in image even using jQuery or flash plugin .

Comment: So what we need do for you? what is your question

Comment: what is input and what is your required output?

Comment: You should give some more details so that your question can be answered.

Comment: You can use a javascript library for data visualization like D3js (http://d3js.org) look at examples, you can work with json data, csv... etc, it is very powerfull and flexible, maybe will be usefull for you.

Comment: Input is the chracactor sequence in arrays.                        thanks  vzamanillo ,,I came up with my own solution using JavaScript.Hope to make it chart plugin.